# Добавить класс элементу JS с условием

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Как добавить класс элемнету если таковых на странице меньше двух или трех.

Например есть:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Все имеют ширину:

```
width: 33.333%
```

Есть страницы на которых выводится только два или один блок, получается не очень красиво выглядит. Есть ли на jQuery решение позволяющее задать условие, что если элементов меньше чем 3 то добавляется дополнительный класс, содержащий например:

```
width: 50%;
```

Или если элемент .products только один, ему присваивается класс содержащий:

```
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Описал стили для наглядности задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var block_len = $('.block').length;

    if(block_len == 3)
        $('.block').addClass('class-name');//если 3
    else if(block_len == 2)
        $('.block').addClass('class-name-50');// если 2
    else if(block_len == 1)
        $('.block').addClass('class-name-50-mg');// если 1

});
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Это легко решается с помощью `CSS` и [`Flex`](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/):

```js
function add(wr){
  if(wr.children.length < 9)
    wr.innerHTML += `<div class='some'>${parseInt(wr.querySelector('.some:last-child').textContent) + 1}</div>`;
}

function remove(wr){
  if(wr.children.length > 1)
    wr.querySelector('.some:last-child').remove();
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wr')
  
  document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function(){add.call(null, wr)});
  document.querySelector('#rem').addEventListener('click', function(){remove.call(null, wr)});
});
```

```css
#wr{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.some{
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 10%;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id='wr'>
  <div class='some'>1</div>
  <div class='some'>2</div>
  <div class='some'>3</div>
</div>
<hr />
<input type='button' id='add' value='+' /> | <input type='button' id='rem' value='-' />
```

`JS` только для реализации кнопок для примера.

Comment: Спасибо, но flex в моем случае не подходит.

Comment: Его уже все поддерживают и достаточно давно, если Вы об этом.